# Website contact form suddenly stopped working after years of working?

Tags: php, forms, email, client, contacts

Hello when i submit the form i get current error of

> Warning: `mail()` [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server. in ../.../..../ on line ....

I wasn't getting this error message until I removed the `@` symbol from the `mail()` and it would send it to my email until around last month. I dont understand what the error is or whats wrong please help

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "test@live.com.au";

    $email_subject = "Subject....";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like the SMTP server changed the way it handles these kind of requests.

Comment: - change the smtp server settings to allow relaying from the server's ip address     or 
 - set up & use 'smtp authentication' which should allow you to send anywhere.

Comment: How would i change the server settings to allow relaying from the server's ip??

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you are using the php mail() command - which then sends it through the smtp server listed in the php.ini file.

However, when it gets to that server, it's saying "hey, you're not sending to me - you're sending to an external address. I'm not going to let you".

You can do one of two things to resolve this: 
1. change the smtp server settings to allow relaying from the server's ip address 
2. set up & use 'smtp authentication' which should allow you to send anywhere. This will most likely be set up on the smtp server already so you just need to go to the Interspire Email Marketer settings page and put in the appropriate details in the 'SMTP Server' section.

Source: https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/574/Warning%3A+mail()+%5Bfunction.mail%5D%3A+SMTP+server+response%3A+503+This+mail+server+requires+authentication+when+attempting+to+send+to+a+non-local+e-mail+address

Comment: How would 1 simply change the smtp server settings to allow relaying from the server's ip address

Comment: How would you be able to change the server setting?